# Is there a good counter to wedge + biggs combo?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

I face a lot of wedge + biggs (and normally Lando as well) in squad arena right now - are there any leaders in the game or mods that I can get that are considered a good counter to this crazy area of effect + crit combination? What counterplay options are available to me?

Comment: Saw your edit to my answer, I've tweaked it and added some more info on current teams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Palpatine.  If he's fast enough and survives the initial round of damage then he can usually stun most of the other team and let you kill Wedge and Biggs.  You need good damage dealers with him, and possibly Storm Trooper Han.
- Sith in general, especially with a Zeta Darth Maul lead.  This is the "Meta" right now and simply outclasses most other teams — the Evasion, Stealth, and damage bonuses make it hard to pin one of them down before they handily destroy Wiggs.  Their debuffs are also very effective against Rebels.  Sith Assassin is especially powerful under "Zaul", and I've had great success using Nihilus to one-shot Biggs near the end of the match (after neutering him by taking out Wedge early).
- Rex lead, since he gives everyone Turn Meter if they are critically hit and is fast enough (with Speed mods if needed) to go second and gives your team immunity to negative effects and more turn meter.  You'd want some high-damage characters backing him, and maybe Storm Trooper Han.
- Several of the newer tanks: General Kenobi, Baze Malbus, and Shoretrooper. The latter two start encounters with a taunt already up, and Shoretrooper can give your entire team critical hit immunity as soon as he takes his first turn.  Baze also starts with Retribution and Kenobi can grant it to the whole team (and he taunts when his allies take damage).  This neuters a lot of Wiggs' damage or turns it back on them, and their high HP pools ensure that they will be difficult to defeat before the other characters on your team take out Wiggs.

  Kenobi or Baze are often paired with Rex, whereas Shoretrooper works best with Empire (under Palpatine or Zeta Darth Vader).
- A standard Droid team (HK leader, 86, 88, Jawa Engineer, and either B2 or Nebit).  You need to take out Wedge and then other risks like Lando first, avoiding hitting Biggs with crits until they are dead first.
- Other evasion teams work, especially Old Ben lead with a fast STH.  STH will probably go second and his taunt and TM gain for the team can save you.